# I can't edit array nested in React using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm practicing React with Redux and in this stage edit or update a nested array. I can't get it to work for me.

State default (array of objects):

```
[
{
  "id": 10,
  "title": "president",
  "totalParticipants": 0,
  "desc": "Selects a new member to represent",
  "options": [
    {
      "id": 1408,
      "nameOption": "Kim",
      "vote": 0,
      "checked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 1527,
      "nameOption": "North",
      "vote": 0,
      "checked": false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 11,
  "title": "best players",
  "totalParticipants": 0,
  "desc": "Selects a new best player",
  "options": [
    {
      "id": 150,
      "nameOption": "Jhon",
      "vote": 0,
      "checked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 152,
      "nameOption": "Gerald",
      "vote": 0,
      "checked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 153,
      "nameOption": "Sofi",
      "vote": 0,
      "checked": false
    }

  ]
},
]
```

I have a function reducer

```
case 'ADD_VOTE':
  const getPoll = action.values.map(poll => poll);

  // get index to option
  const optionIndex = getPoll.map(dat => (
    dat.options.findIndex(opt => opt.id === action.id)
  ));

  // get value to options
  // const option = action.vote.map(opt => opt.options[projectIndex]);
  const optionVal = action.values.map(poll => (
    poll.options[optionIndex]
  ))
         
  const nextPoll = {
    ...action.values,
    options:[
      { vote:  + 1  }
    ]
  };
       
  return {
    ...state,
    nextPoll
  }
```

And function action

```
export const addVotePoll = ({ id }, values) => ({
  type: 'ADD_VOTE',
  id,
  values,
})
```

When I throw dispatch event it passes `idSelected` and data of poll current.

For example: I will select name option `"KIM"` (state default), then send `id` (1408) and send data of poll... (idPoll, title, desc, option, etc).

I read something about immutable.js but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: `return { ...state, ...nextPoll }` would make much more sense, but this will still clear `options`, because you didn't include the old value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand of your description, you are trying to dispatch the `addVotePoll` action to increment the vote count of a specific entry in the `options` array by `id`. To apply the [immutable update pattern](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) you must shallow copy all state, and nested state, that is being updated.

Example:

```
case 'ADD_VOTE':
  // return shallow copy of state array
  return state.map(poll => poll.id === action.values.idPoll
    ? {
      ...poll,                    // <-- shallow copy current state
      options: poll.options.map(  // <-- shallow copy options
        option => option.id === action.id
          ? {
            ...option,             // <-- shallow copy matched option
            vote: option.vote + 1, // <-- update specific property
          }
          : option
      ),
    }
    : poll
  );
```

Comment: Thanks Drew Reese this work to edit array nested, but now i have the new array but need add this array a poll

Comment: @Rioko Can you clarify what "now i have the new array but need add this array a poll" means?

Comment: I have a default state, this is a poll, where we edit the options, but now how do I add this array to the poll that comes from the actions

Comment: @Rioko Sorry, what poll and what array are you referring to? The only array I see in your code is the `options` array. Are you trying to add another property to the state?

Comment: Sorry, the default state is edited in post.
thanks for readme

Comment: @Rioko I see, so the state is an array of objects (polls?), and in these objects is an `options` array. Are you asking then how to update a specific poll object?

Comment: yes that exactly

Comment: @Rioko Ok, and so `values` is the poll object with the `pollId` property to match up to one of the outer array elements?

Comment: yes, with your help I have been able to edit the array of options that belongs to a particular survey

Comment: @Rioko Ok, thanks for all the clarification, I've updated my answer with what I believe to be the understanding.